# What's the easternmost place in Asia?

Tags: adventure, factoids, asia, geography

On my current trip (like my previous) I've been in Europe and crossed the Bosphorous to Asia and proceeded further east (currently Tbilisi, Georgia).

At some point I'd like to move even further east, ideally all the way across Russia to Japan.

This (plus some talk in [the travel chat room, "You Are Here"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here)) got me thinking, **how east can I go in Asia?** Would it be some point on one of the main islands of Japan? Some smaller Japanese island? Or somewhere else that I totally failed to think of?

Comment: Does Australia count as part of Asia? :)

Comment: What is the northernmost or southernmost place in ... will usually have a simple and satisfying answer but easternmost and westernmost can be tricky due to the arbitrary location of 0 E/W and hence 180E/W.    If a country crosses one of these imaginary lines then the answer will not be the obvious cases of a bit of coastline or border with another country.  It probably won't even be a point.  Jan admits that his answer is tongue in cheek but it might be the most defensible.  Consider what are the northernmost. southernmost, easternmost, and westernmost points of Antarctica.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's not Japan, it is Russia!

Wikipedia has a good article about [extreme points of Eurasia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_points_of_Eurasia).

Comment: Ha! I tried Googling "eastermost Asia" but it returned other extremes of Asia and eastermost extremes of other places. Didn't expect this but of course.

Comment: I really doubt that. The Ural mountains that are in Russia divide Europe and Asia. Most of the part of Russia is clearly in Asia.

Answer (score 8):

Tongue-in-cheek answer:

The easternmost place in Asia is where the Russian Far East touches the 180° meridian. It’s actually a line of over 400 km (estimated by grabbing coordinates from the southern coast to the northern coast and taking the difference in latitude) which also happens to form part of the easternmost land on Earth.

Just a step away is (are) the westernmost point(s) of Asia at 179.999…° W. So you can have the distinction of standing on the westernmost and easternmost points of a continent at the same time.

Answer (score 7):

If you are only talking about the non-Russian part of Asia, then the answer would be [Minami Torishima](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minami_Torishima) which located in 24°16′59″N 153°59′11″E
It's very near to Iwo Jima and has a alias "Marcus Island".

In the map below Minami Torishima is marked with **"A"**. You can compare it with the red line, which is actually the easternmost area of Indonesia.

[image]

The photo of the island.Notice the unique triangular shape.
[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with this term "EuroAsia". Are you sure you don't mean "Eurasia"? If so are you saying Siberia is in the European side of it??

Comment: Siberia is actually part of Russia, which is actually East Europe. And sorry the EuroAsia is an typo. Should be Eurasia.

Comment: I never heard that Siberia is Europe...

Comment: I always thought Russia, like Turkey, spans two continents thus having a European part and an Asian part. I've never heard Anatolia or Siberia described as being in Europe before. According to Wikipedia: "Siberia is an extensive region constituting almost all of Northern Asia". I think you might be confusing politics and geography. I still voted you up though for the most eastern part of Asia not in Russia.

Comment: Also Eurasia is not a third place besides Europe and Asia, but the combination of Europe and Asia seen as a whole.

Comment: Just realized that Siberia is part of Asia. But now wonder why Russia never send contingent to Asian Games.

Comment: @Rudy: That's a good point! We were talking about on chat how they do send teams to European sporting events.

Comment: @Rudy Because of the rules - we are sending our sportsmans to the European championships, and has no right to send them to over official sport events.

Comment: Russia is more Asian than European.

Comment: Note that I has admitted that I'm wrong, thus there is no need downvote me.

Comment: @Rudy: perhaps you should update your answer to avoid further downvotes...

Answer (score 5):

[Kamchatka Peninsula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamchatka_Peninsula)! Full of bears, salmon, mountains, and all kinds of other cool stuff =)

Comment: This is actually incorrect. [Chukchi Peninsula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chukchi_Peninsula) is a good deal further East, albeit East of the 180° meridian.

Answer (score -2):

The easternmost part of Asia is actually the island of Attu. Attu is off the coast of Alaska, but so far west it crosses into Asia.  Look it up.

Comment: Better look it up yourself ;-) Attu is the westernmost place of Alaska, not the eastermost place of Asia.

Comment: Actually, the fact that it is the westernmost place in Alaska does not preclude it from being part of Asia or preclude it from being further east than other parts of Asia. To say otherwise is the same as saying that if you didn't sleep for 25 hours that you were only awake for one hour.